# differences betwen game resolution in a different display resolution

Tags: c++, cocos2d

my game is not supported on the other devices with a different resolutions. for example may character is 140w X 55h pixels which is ok on a 4 inch display but it goes wide when i tested my game on a device with 4.7 inch display. how can i make a correct character for 4.7 or more inch displays? 
i am using cocos2d-x engine. i want to see if it has a automatic synchronize tool or no. i my self must do it manually ?

Comment: I recommend you [this answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/90405/cocos2d-x-supporting-multi-resolution-using-density-independent-pixels/90406#90406). It will help you resolving all your resolution problem with cocos2d.

Answer (score 1):

What you see right now is cause by aspect ratio change (for example from 3/2 to 16/9) which causes everything to look wide.
There are multiple ways that you might fix this issue:

The easiest one is to tell engine what is your design resolution, and how should engine respond to resolution changes. Should it scale everything to completely fit the screen? or place a black border in the sides, while maintaining aspect ratio? or some few other options.

Another option is to provide more than one set of resources for different devices and when the game is loading, choose one according to your device resolution.

For more information read about multiple resolution support in this link:

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Multi_resolution_support